# getting last element of a list of unknown size using slices

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, slice

Let's say I have a list of unknown size, then I can access the last element using:

```
>>> l = list(range(10))
>>> l[-1]
9
```

However, is there any way to do this via a slice object like

```
>>> s = slice(-1, 10)
>>> l[s]
[9]
```

without knowing the length of my list?

**Edit:**

I simplified my Question a bit. I am fine with getting a list back, since I am iterating over the sublist later. I just needed a way of getting the last item of list besides being able to get every second element and so on ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, just use `None` as the `end` argument:

```
In [53]: l[slice(-1, None)]
Out[53]: [9]
```

This will of course produce a list `[9]`, rather than the `9` in your question, because slicing a list always produces a sublist rather than a bare element.

Comment: Great, thats exactly what I was looking for! The docs are a bit sparse.

Comment: @schwobaseggl I can't use len(l) here, since I want to pass the slice as function argument. Hence l is unknown when the slice is created.

Comment: Also this will return an empty list if your list is empty (not sure if that's what you want though)

Answer (score 1):

If your objective is to pass arguments which you can use to index a list, you can use [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
from operator import itemgetter

L = range(10)

itemgetter(-1)(L)  # 9
```

In my opinion, for this specific task, `itemgetter` is cleaner than extracting a list via a slice, then extracting the only element of the list.

Note also that this works on a wider range of objects than just lists, e.g. with `range` as above.

Answer (score 0):

If you were to access the last element of the list:

```
n = int(input())
user_input = [int(input) for i in range(n)]
last_element = user_input[-1]
```

Here we have used negative indices concept in lists.